# ¿C# Como cambiar el formato de DateTime de dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss a yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss?

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime, visual

Estoy tratando de agregar datos a una tabla de Oracle a traves de C#, pero el formato que solicita mi tabla es yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, sin embargo DateTime me esta arrojando este formato: MM/dd/YYYY hh:mm:ss tt, incluyo el codigo de ejemplo que ando tratando con DateTime.ParseExact:

```
string x = "2020-09-08 05:36:15";
DateTime fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

El resultado que recibo por parte de fecha = "9/3/2020 5:32:20 AM"

Por ende literal se necesita agregar la fecha como el string original, pero al convertirlo al DateTime se convierte con el formato resultante y con AM/PM en vez de 24H.

Ojala puedan ayudarme :)

Comment: como realizas el INSERT del dato a la tabla de Oracle? porque creo que el datetime y el formato no tienen nada que ver con el problema, sino como asignas ese valor al command que ejecutas

Answer (score 2):

Internamente DateTime se guarda con un formato y cuando lo imprimimos es cuando podemos variar el formato de salida. He añadido una línea a tu código para que veas la diferencia:

```
string x = "2020-09-08 05:36:15";
DateTime fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

// Muestra la fecha con el formato actual
Console.WriteLine(fecha.ToString());
// Muestra la fcha con el formato pasado como parámetro
Console.WriteLine(fecha.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Observa que en la última línea se imprime una cadena que se obtiene de dar formato al objeto fecha y comprobarás que se muestra adecuadamente. Por tanto, en tu tabla de Oracle o bien pasas la cadena (no el objeto fecha) o bien generas las fecha con el formato devuelto.